# Getting the values in a matrix with row and column names stored in a dataframe

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

Suppose I have a matrix `rmatrix` defined below:

```
set.seed(10)
rmatrix  <-  matrix(sample(0:100, 16), ncol=4)
dimnames(rmatrix) <- list(rownames(rmatrix, do.NULL = FALSE, 
   prefix = "row"), colnames(rmatrix, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "col"))
rmatrix

     col1 col2 col3 col4
row1   51    8   57   10
row2   30   21   39   52
row3   42   26   59   31
row4   67   25  100   36
```

A dataframe `df` stores some combinations of the row and column names of `rmatrix`:

```
df <- data.frame(r = c('row1', 'row1', 'row3', 'row4', 'row4', 'row4'), 
   c = c('col2', 'col4', 'col3', 'col3', 'col1', 'col2'))
df
     r    c
1 row1 col2
2 row1 col4
3 row3 col3
4 row4 col3
5 row4 col1
6 row4 col2
```

How to obtain the values in `rmatrix` for those combinations in `df`?

**Added**: Actually I want to change any element in `rmatrix` to `NA` if it is not in `df`. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: `apply(df, 1, function(x) rmatrix[x['r'], x['c']])` but there must be something better.