# Operation of matrix in R based on dimension names

Tags: r, matrix

I have a symmetric matrix `s` defined as:

```
s<-matrix(1:25,5)
s[lower.tri(s)] = t(s)[lower.tri(s)]
dimnames(s) <- list(LETTERS[1:5], LETTERS[1:5])
s

   A  B  C  D  E
A  1  6 11 16 21
B  6  7 12 17 22
C 11 12 13 18 23
D 16 17 18 19 24
E 21 22 23 24 25
```

In addition, there is a vector `t` defined as:

```
t <- seq(1,10)
names(t) <- c('C_A', 'E_A', 'E_B', 'E_C', 'E_D', 'D_A', 'D_B', 'D_C', 'C_B', 'A_B')
```

Now I would like to add the elements of `t` to the upper and lower triangular elements of `s` in such a way that the element of `t` with the name 'C_A' is added to the elements of `s` with row and column names of 'C' and 'A' (or 'A' and 'C'), the element of `t` with the name 'E_A' is added to the elements of `s` with row and column names of 'E' and 'A' (or 'A' and 'E'), etc. For example, both s['A','B'] and s['B','A'] should be added by t['A_B'], and similarly for all other off-diagonal elements. Do nothing for the diagonals.

What is an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? You were linked to a relevant post in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338800/getting-the-values-in-a-matrix-with-row-and-column-names-stored-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `outer` to create row/col and col/row indexes, then overwrite the corresponding values of `s`:

```
sel1 <- match(names(t), outer(rownames(s),colnames(s), function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep="_")))
sel2 <- match(names(t), outer(rownames(s),colnames(s), function(x,y) paste(y,x,sep="_")))
s[sel1] <- s[sel1]+t
s[sel2] <- s[sel2]+t

#   A  B  C  D  E
#A  1 16 12 22 23
#B 16  7 21 24 25
#C 12 21 13 26 27
#D 22 24 26 19 29
#E 23 25 27 29 25
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not especially elegant but:

```r
s<-matrix(1:25,5)
s[lower.tri(s)] = t(s)[lower.tri(s)]
dimnames(s) <- list(LETTERS[1:5], LETTERS[1:5])

t <- seq(1,10)
names(t) <- c('C_A', 'E_A', 'E_B', 'E_C', 'E_D', 'D_A', 'D_B', 'D_C', 'C_B', 'A_B')

s[t(do.call(cbind, strsplit(names(t), split = "_")))] <-
  s[t(do.call(cbind, strsplit(names(t), split = "_")))] + t
s
#>    A  B  C  D  E
#> A  1 16 11 16 21
#> B  6  7 12 17 22
#> C 12 21 13 18 23
#> D 22 24 26 19 24
#> E 23 25 27 29 25
```

To add the [i,j]th elements just call it again with the index positions reversed

```r
s[t(do.call(cbind, strsplit(names(t), split = "_")))[,2:1]] <-
      s[t(do.call(cbind, strsplit(names(t), split = "_")))[,2:1]] + t
s
#>    A  B  C  D  E
#> A  1 16 12 22 23
#> B 16  7 21 24 25
#> C 12 21 13 26 27
#> D 22 24 26 19 29
#> E 23 25 27 29 25
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that some elements in `s` were not added correctly? For example, s['B', 'A'], s['D', 'A'], etc.. Also the upper triangular part was not added.

Comment: s['A','B'] is 6 and should have the tenth element added to it so it should be 16 as in the result no? And the point ['A', 'D'] is not in t. maybe I am confused as to your desired output?

Comment: Sorry. Both s['A','B'] and s['B','A'] should be added by t['A_B'], and similarly for all other off-diagonal elements. I'll clarify it in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Err: Will fix:</strike> You can use matrix indexing with a two-column matrix of character values for row and col:

```
nt <- strsplit(names(t), "_")
dnt <- data.frame(n=t, t(data.frame(nt)))
s[ as.matrix(dnt[-1]) ] <- s[ as.matrix(dnt[-1]) ] + t
s
#-----------
   A  B  C  D  E
A  1 16 11 16 21
B  6  7 12 17 22
C 12 21 13 18 23
D 22 24 26 19 24
E 23 25 27 29 25
 s[as.matrix(dnt[c(3,2)])] <- s[as.matrix(dnt[c(3,2)])] + t
s
#----------
   A  B  C  D  E
A  1 16 13 28 25
B 26  7 30 31 28
C 12 21 13 34 31
D 22 24 26 19 34
E 23 25 27 29 25
```

Comment: I thought I did. I missed the fact that you wanted `t` added in an earlier version

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 <- as.list(t)
p <- for(i in 1 :length(t1))
{
  nam <-unlist(strsplit(names(t1[i]),"_"))
  s[nam[1],nam[2]]<- t[[i]]
  s[nam[2],nam[1]]<- t[[i]]
}

> s
   A  B  C  D  E
A  1 10  1  6  2
B 10  7  9  7  3
C  1  9 13  8  4
D  6  7  8 19  5
E  2  3  4  5 25
```

Comment: The final result does not seem to be correct? I verified the answer by @gfgm.